# Asp.net C# :Add New Row in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to create a new row in `GridView` on button click with the values of `labels` :

```
<Asp:Label id="Label1" runat="Server" Text="My name">
<Asp:Label id="Label2" runat="Server" Text="My Age">
<Asp:Label id="Label3" runat="Server" Text="My Gender">
```

The following `GridView` contains `Label` `TemplateFields`

```
    <Asp:Gridview runat="Server" Id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">   
    <Columns>   

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Name_lbl" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>   

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Age_lbl" Text='<%# Eval("Age")%>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField> 

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Gender_lbl" Text='<%# Eval("Gender")%>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField> 

 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In `Button_Click`, `Label` values will be inserted into the gridview.

**My Attempts** in inserting `Label` values into `GridView` but i get error: `"DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'"`

```
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            Label1.Text =( gvr.FindControl("Name_lbl") as Label).ToString();
            Label2.Text = (gvr.FindControl("Age_lbl") as Label).ToString();
            Label3.Text = (gvr.FindControl("Gender_lbl") as Label).ToString();

            dr[1] =  Label1.Text;
            dr[2] =  Label2.Text;
            dr[3] =  Label3.Text;


            dt.Rows.Add(dr); 
        }
        dr = dt.NewRow(); 
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Does it gives any Error?

Comment: @RahulHendawe i didnt write the on button click code to add new row into the gridview, so no errors

Comment: by your provided code, attempt, you try to put control (from `GridView`) into `Label` text (??)... wrong and opposite from what you want... even if you go to right way you still need to define in which row looking for label (`GridView` `FindControl`).

Comment: @nelek all i know is define footer row like:    `GridView1.FooterRow.findcontrol(....)` but i dont want to use footer row. What do i do ??

Comment: If you need to add a row to the Grid, you should add the row to the list/datatable/other structure that the grid is databound to. Then rebind the grid.

Comment: @user1429080 Currently i am looking to add the row into `datable` and then bind the `GridView` to the `datatable` if that will solve the issue. but still didnt figure it out.